# Java Method to find the occurencies of a certain character

Tags: java, string, char

my code should prompt the user to enter a string and a character, and tell where the character is located
for instance
"Welcome" and "e"
returns
"2, 7"

How can my code be fixed? Code is here. Thanks in advance (this is not homework, but some hint could be useful anyway if you don't want to post a solution).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a string and a character");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = input.nextLine();
        char ch = input.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.println(count(ch));

    }

    public static int count (String s, char a) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == a) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;

    }
}
```

Comment: First hint: If you want your method to return a comma-separated list of numbers, you should make the return type `String`, not `int`.  An `int` is a single number.

Comment: As @DavidWallace said, what your program prints is the number of occurrences in int. If you want to print the indices too, you could try making an int array to store each index of the character you're finding occurrences of, and print it using a for loop.

Comment: why you named the method as count instead of find ?

Comment: Your code does something quite different, namely counting occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some mistakes:

1. Your code doesn't compile. Call:

   ```
   System.out.println(count(s, ch));
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   System.out.println(count(ch));
   ```
2. You count the number of appearances. Instead, you should keep the indexes. You can use a `String` or you can add them to a list / array and convert it later to what you want.

   ```
   public static String count(String s, char a) {
       String result = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
           if (s.charAt(i) == a) {
               result += (i+1) + ", ";
           }
       }
       return result.substring(0, result.length() - 2);
   }
   ```

   I used `i+1` instead of `i` because the indexes start at `0` in Java.

   I also returned the string `result.substring(0, result.length() - 2)` without its last 2 characters, because I added `,` after every character.

Answer (score 1):

Since **Java 8**, you can do this by using *streams*:

```
public static String count(String s, char a) {
    return IntStream.range(0, s.length())
            .filter(i -> a == s.charAt(i)).mapToObj(i -> i + "")
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

This code will print indexes of your Character, seprated by comma.
For more about *streams*, you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), in Java 8 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the count method :

```
   public static ArrayList<Integer> count(String s, char a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == a) {
                positions.add(i+1);
            }
        }
        return positions;
   }
```